# Getting Outlook notification on more than just Inbox messages

Tags: email, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2011

Outlook can notify the user every time a new email is received in the Inbox folder. (On Mac it also shows the # of unread messages in the Inbox).

I have some server rules setup which makes certain emails go straight to a custom folder. I was wondering if there is an easy way to make Outlook do this before new messages in **All** folders or better yet, some customizable set of folders.

I am using Outlook 2011 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to get a notification for a customizable set of folders in Outlook 2011 on Mac. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a free easy way to do it. I was able to purchase Growl ($1.99 on Mac App Store) and use this "outlook_growl_new_mail.zip" AppleScript along with a custom Outlook Rule to select the folders I wanted to watch:

http://mattgemmell.com/2010/11/03/using-growl-with-microsoft-outlook-2011-mac/

You do not need to edit the AppleScript at all, just add an Outlook Rule and under "Do the following" select "Run AppleScript..." and choose the file.

Comment: My Outlook 2011 on mac has no "Run AppleScript..." option in the rule actions. How do I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone seems to have solved this issue elsewhere: See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/notifications-in-outlook-for-mac-2011/b573a53f-0cd1-4da9-80ec-c72308e36070?auth=1

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a *client side rule* to display a notification when a folder gets a new email.

1. Top Menu Bar > Messages > Rules > Edit Rules (Screenshot 1)
2. `Rules` popup > Sidebar > Under `Client Rules` section > select `Exchange` (Screenshot 2)
3. Tap the `+` button at the bottom of the popup (Screenshot 2)
4. Set rule to `If any conditions are met` (Screenshot 3)
5. Add all the folders you want notifications on (Screenshot 3)
6. Set `Do the following` to `Display Notification` (Screenshot 3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see option for `2. Client Rules > Exchange > Add Rule`. Where is this?

Comment: Hi @Snebhu, the first screenshot shows you how to open the popup `Rules`. The `Rules` window has a sidebar. The sidebar has `Client Rules` section. The second screenshot shows the `Exchange` option under the `Client Rules`. Once you have selected `Exchange`, use the `+` at the bottom of the screen to add a new rule. I've updated the steps to better explain that, thanks!